# Choose randomly between two <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I click on "PLAY" , it dissapears then show "STOP" button.

```
<a onclick="$('#detecteur-play').hide();$('#ID1').show();" id="detecteur-play">Play</a>

<a style="display:none;" id="ID1">STOP1</a>
<a style="display:none;" id="ID2">STOP2</a>
```

With this code it will show me always the same "STOP1" link. Now I want to choose randomly between my `STOP1` or `STOP2` link but I have no idea how to do that. How can I do this ?

Comment: `Math.random()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/asedoj/1/edit

Don't use inline JS, it's hardly maintainable.
Create a function that will generate for you random numbers in a desired range:

```
<a id="detecteur-play">Play</a>

<a style="display:none;" id="ID1">STOP1</a>
<a style="display:none;" id="ID2">STOP2</a>
```

```
// Reusable Randomizer function
function ran(min, max) {
  return ~~(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
}

$('#detecteur-play').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $('#ID'+ran(1,2)).show();
});
```

The ~~ Operator I used is a double NOT bitwise operator, used to replace `Math.floor`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work fine:

```
$("a[id^=ID]:eq(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * $("a[id^=ID]").length) + ")").show();
```

**What are we doing?**

Let's take it from the inside out. We use `Math.random()` which gives us a random number between 0 and 1 (eg. 0.223) and we multiply it by the amount of `<a>` elements. If `Math.random()` returned `0.6`, and there was 2 `<a>` elements, we'd get rounded to `1`, else we'd get rounded to `0`. Then we floor the value (you can't have an index of `0.282`, to get either `0` or `1`. Finally we use the `eq()` filter to say that we only want the nth `<a>` element and we use `show()` to show it. Our `a` selector, `a[id^=ID]` means "*a elements with an `id` attribute starting with the string `ID`*".

Comment: I think you would want to add a selector to match only links with ids starting  with "ID"

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/txGuu/8/

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
$("#ID"+r).show();
```

Comment: it return 1 or 2 (ID1 or ID2)